# How to access apps that have been deployed in k8s on Google Cloud Platform using a Google Cloud Engine HTTP(S) Load Balancer?

Tags: load-balancing, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, healthcheck

**Aim:** to access apps that reside in a kubernetes (k8s) namespace using an HTTP(S) Load Balancer (HLB)

**Methods**

*TCP load balancing (TLB) (layer 4)*

- A k8s cluster has been created on Google Cloud Platform (GCP)
- A static IP was created
- A TLB was created, the static IP was assigned and the DNS has been updated
- Navigating to some.domain.com shows the app that has been deployed in the ‘some’ namespace
- another.domain.com shows the app that runs inside the ‘another’ namespace
- When additional namespaces are deployed, e.g. something-else then going to something-else.domain.com returns the app from that namespace as well.

*HTTP(S) load balancing (layer 7)*

- The assumption was that the apps could be accessed the same way, i.e. just replace the TLB with the layer 7 one.
- One of the official GCP was followed, backend was configured, default path was left as is and certificates were configured in the frontend section
- The DNS was updated
- After five minutes a HTTP 502 was returned when some.domain.com was consulted
- The ingress nginx log POD log was tailed, but no additional logging was added when the some.domain.com was refreshed
- The GCP logging indicated that there is a ‘backend error’
- The healthcheck of the loadbalancer was not working well initially and when a check 10256 HTTP was added the service became green
- When one navigates to some of the namespaces the following error is shown:

> **Error: Server Error**
>
> The server encountered a temporary error and could
>   not complete your request.
>
> Please try again in 30 seconds.

**Discussion**

- Although the same health check, i.e. the one that is used for the TLB was added and turned the HLB to green, this could be a false positive.
- According to [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32188284/2777965), the issue is caused by an unhealthy service, but the TCP check 10256 was added, turned the service into green and then the issue persisted. Should another check by added?
- The assumption that the TLB would work the same looks incorrect. According to the GCP log the HLB cannot even route the traffic to a namespace.

**Sub-questions**

- What health check should be configured to check HLB?
- How does the routing of HLB deviate from TLB?

Comment: Hello, could you specify which `Ingress` controller are you using? By the question it seems like it's `ingress-gke` but you've posted: `The ingress nginx log POD log was tailed, ` which could indicate you are using `ingress-nginx`. This are 2 separate identities and HTTPS Load Balancer is available to use with `ingress-gke`. With `ingress-nginx` you are creating `TCP`/`UDP` LoadBalancer that is pointing to `ingress-nginx` controller that with `Ingress` resource route the packets further.

Comment: Do you still have this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at below GCP documentation:

1. [Setting up](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer) HTTP(S) Load Balancing with Ingress - This documenation provides a tutorial on how to run a web application behind an external HTTP(S) load balancer by configuring the Ingress resource, which is a great help.
2. Exposing applications using [services](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/exposing-apps) - Here you create a Deployment and expose its Pods by creating a Service (i.e. ClusterIP (default), NodePort, LoadBalancer, ExternalName or Headless). Then you send an HTTP request to the Service.
3. How [health checks](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-check-concepts#method) work - Here you will be able to verify Probe IP ranges and firewall rules required for health check.